# Error loading xml data in my RTF template: "An invalid character was found in text content."

Tags: bi-publisher

Upon loading my data on RTF template, I am getting an error saying

> "An invalid character was found in text content".

I extracted the `xml` data from BI Publisher. Is there any fix on BI Publisher in order to fix this issue? I only get this error when loading the data on my template online. I think the error comes from the **NUL** character in the picture below:

[image]